# Image corrupt or truncated in firefox generated by php script

Tags: image, firefox, symfony-1.4, captcha

I have a problem with a php script which generate captcha from png image . everything is alright with ie and chrome . the problem appears while testing the script in a firefox browser .

My code :

```
 function executeGenerateCaptcha()
{
  header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
  // number of characters to type
  define('NB_CARACTERE', 6);
  $sImage = imagecreatefrompng(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../captcha/images/fond.png');
  $nCpt   = 0;

// possible characters for captcha
  $aChars = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';

// string generation
  while ($nCpt < NB_CARACTERE)
  {
    $sCaractere         = $aChars{ mt_rand(0, strlen($aChars) - 1)};
    $aCaracteres[$nCpt] = $sCaractere;
    $nCpt++;
  }

  $sCode        = null;
  $iAbcisse     = 0;
  $iInclinaison = -20;

// characters generation on image
  foreach ($aCaracteres as $sCaractere)
  {
    $sCode .= $sCaractere;
    $color = imagecolorallocate($sImage, mt_rand(0, 253), mt_rand(0, 253), mt_rand(0, 253));
    imagettftext($sImage, 40, $iInclinaison, 0 + $iAbcisse, 45, $color, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../captcha/images/arial.ttf', $sCaractere);

    $iAbcisse     = $iAbcisse + 30;
    $iInclinaison = $iInclinaison - 12;
  }

  unset($sCaractere);
  unset($nCpt);
  unset($sCaractere);
  unset($aCaracteres);

  imagepng($sImage);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to add 'flush();' at the end of function to save the generated image.

Comment: I got the error `flush is not defined` when I tried this.